# Strange behaviour when passing values from a float array to a double array (C, C++)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, floating-point-precision, nidaqmx

I am developing an application that uses NI-DAQ and below are some methods which were given by the provider.

```
void someMethod(Calibration *cal, float myArray[], float result[]) 
{
    newMethod(&cal->rt,myArray,result,cal->cfg.TempCompEnabled);
}

void newMethod(RTCoefs *coefs, double myArray[],float result[],BOOL tempcomp) 
{
float newMyArray[6];
    unsigned short i;

    for (i=0; i < 6; i++) 
    {
         newMyArray[i]=myArray[i];
    }

}
```

I basically call someMethod(), providing an array with six elements ( [6] ) for both myArray[] and result[]. As you can see in the code, afterwards the newMethod() is called, and float myArray[6] is passed to the double myArray[] argument (I really do not understand why the developer of this code chose to use a double array, since the only array declared inside the newMethod() is a float type).

Now here comes my problem: inside the for loop, some values are passed without any problem, but when the fourth and fifth values are passed to newMyArray[], it receives "-1.#INF0000" for both values. At first glance, I thought that it would be some garbage value, but "-1.#INF0000" is there at every execution.

I know that C language can be tricky sometimes, but I really do not know why this is happening...

Comment: which language is this? C and C++ are different.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Not in this case.

Comment: @JamesKanze in C++ there could be other overloads of newMethod (amongst other possibilities)

Comment: It would help if you gave us the values in `myArray`. I suspect range issues.

Comment: @Mudkip in C you must get a compilation error for the line `newMethod(&cal->rt,myArray,result,cal->cfg.TempCompEnabled);` because `float *` cannot be converted to match `double *`.  This error should not be ignored!

Comment: You can convert from float to double without fear but if you try to do the other way you might get the number being truncated or some other funny stuff

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I think it would be a compilation error in C++, a warning in C (on a compiler with warnings properly configured).

Comment: @Medinoc the C and C++ standards don't distinguish between "warnings" and "errors", in both languages, if there was a prototype in scope then the compiler must emit a message (but it could go on and generate a bogus executable anyway)

Answer (score 6):

The second parameter to `newMethod` has type `double *`.  But you pass to it a value of type `float *`.

In C++,  or in C if there was a prototype of `newMethod` in scope, this must generate a compilation error.  There is no implicit conversion between pointer types , except for `void *`.

However, in C, if there is no prototype in scope then you may get no warning; just undefined behaviour at runtime because the function was called with arguments of different type (after default argument promotions) to that with which it was defined.

If there is a non-prototype declaration of `newMethod` in scope then you get no warning;  if there was no declaration at all then in C89 the code is legal (i.e. warning is optional) , but in C99 it must warn that `newMethod` was called without being declared.

(So it is important whether this is a C program or a C++ program).

If you are in C and getting no warning, add a prototype before all this:

```
void newMethod(RTCoefs *coefs, double myArray[],float result[],BOOL tempcomp) ;
```

Then you will get a compiler error.

Comment: If there was no prototype, then someMethod wouldn't be able to call newMethod, since the former seems to be defined above the latter. It would seem that the problem is just caused by a bad compiler.

Comment: edited to clarify that point. In C you can have non-prototype declarations of functions (i.e. `void newMethod();`)

Comment: I can smell Visual Studio. Funny how "Visual Studio" and "bad compiler" always pop up in the same context.

Comment: Solved! Just changed the the array type from double to float inside the newMethod() argument. Thank you!

Comment: You mean in the function signature of newMethod? OK, and then you might be able to get rid of `newMyArray` too.  If you didn't get a compiler error first time around then please do add a prototype, it might let the compiler detect other cases of bad calls like this.

Comment: It would also be wise to add in some const-correctness , e.g. if `myArray` is input-only then have the function be `void newMethod(RTCoefs *coefs, double const *myArray,float *result,BOOL tempcomp);` . Then the compiler will also guard against accidental changes to `myArray`'s contents within the function.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the types and the fact that arrays decays to pointers when passed to functions. So when you pass a pointer to a `float` array to `someMethod` it in turn pass it on as a pointer to an array of `double` to `newMethod`. And as you (should) know the size of `float` and the size of `double` is not the same, so in `newMethod` the code is reading data out of bounds from the initial (`float`) array you passed which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The compiler should have given you warnings about that.

Answer (score 0):

`-1.#INF0000` is, I believe, the MSC representation of
a negative infinity.  Which is what you get from a double to
float conversion when the value of the double is too big to be
represented in a float.